# Complex types show no result for a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure I would like to use its result in a Web API (C#).
I must miss something since I'm getting no result nor in `Complex Types` (in EF model) neither in `Functions Imports` (I can see the stored procedure in `Functions Imports` but it does not return any value, as expected).

This is my stored procedure (I have erased some non-important data in order to make it shorter)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


    @main_id BIGINT, 
    @id_ze_mish BIGINT, 
    @id_nof BIGINT, 
    @loggedInUser VARCHAR(20) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION [TransactionUniteSingles]

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY io_key DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE chn_cert

    -- Step 1
    UPDATE [dbo].[t1]
    SET deleted = 1,
    WHERE id_nof = @id_nof
      AND id_ze  = @id_ze_mish

    -- Step 2
    UPDATE [dbo].[t_no_nir]
    SET update_stamp = GETDATE(),
        [user_name] = @loggedInUser
    WHERE id_nof = @id_nof
      AND ms_zehut_mazmin  = @id_ze_mish 

    -- Step 3
    CREATE TABLE #mainPrice
    (
         id INT,
         fName VARCHAR(20),
         lName VARCHAR(20)
    )

    INSERT INTO #mainPrice 
        EXEC  [dbo].[io_sp_get_some_data_foo] @id

    IF(EXISTS(select * from #mainPrice))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @totalAmount INT;

        SELECT @totalAmount = (main_price + price_tip + price_visa) 
        FROM #mainPrice

        DROP TABLE #mainPrice

        UPDATE [dbo].[t_4] 
        SET amount = @totalAmount,
            update_stamp = GETDATE(),
            [user_name] = @loggedInUser
        WHERE id_nof = @id_nof
          AND id  = @main_id

    CLOSE ALL SYMMETRIC KEYS

    COMMIT TRANSACTION [TransactionUniteSingles]      
    SELECT CAST(1 as BIT) as 'Status', 'Succeeded' as 'ReturnMessage'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(0 as BIT) as 'Status', 'ADMIN - Unite Singles as 'ReturnMessage'       
    END 
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [TransactionUniteSingles]
SELECT CAST(0 as BIT) as 'Status', 'ADMIN - Unite Singles' as 'ReturnMessage'       
END CATCH

END
```

Please note  - when running the stored procedure as standalone, it works perfectly and return what expected.

Comment: If you enter your `ELSE`, you never `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK`) your transaction.

Comment: correct.but the issue haven't been solved

Comment: What table is c# reading?  Is it io_sp_get_some_data_foo?  Read table in SSMS and see if it contains data?  It looks like SP is loading the table mainPrice but I'm not sure that is what the c# code is reading.

Comment: @jdweng basically, C# should return the table created by the following `select` : `SELECT CAST(0 as BIT) as 'Status', 'ADMIN - Unite Singles' as 'ReturnMessage'   `

Comment: So where is the C# code that is calling the stored procedure?

Comment: Entity does not look at return values.  It has a mapping to a DataTable in the database.  You could create a View in the DataBase and then have Entity read the View.

Comment: Before dealing with the code, I would like to make sure the SP return what expected(a table with 2 columns in that case) , and it doesn't. in Visual Studio, under the EF model, I have `Complex Types` which should show the result of the C#, which in my case, there is nothing under `Complex Types`. So, I have no reason start writing my code while my SP returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my problem is with my temp table.
when using `SET FMTONLY OFF` at the top of my SP or above the temp table(`#mainPrice` in my case) then everything works like a charm and suddenly the `Complex Types` shows my SP.

Another solution is using a variable table: `DECLARE TABLE @mainPrice`.
Both do the work.

I'll be happy to know why it happens and why C# refused to get a temp table as part of my SP , but at the moment I found the solution needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check what happens when you call your procedure with NULL input parameters. If the result is not a table then EF will not generate the complex result.

Comment: it returns a table. Column 1 = Status(with value 0) and Column 2 = ReturnMessage (with value of `ADMIN - Unite Singles`)

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
-- declare table at SP begin
DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE(
    Status BIT NOT NULL,
    ResultMessage NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

-- insert data where you need
INSERT INTO @ResultTable
(
    Status,
    ResultMessage
)
VALUES
(   NULL, -- Status - bit
    N''   -- ResultMessage - nvarchar(50)
    )

-- at SP end select result from table
SELECT * FROM @ResultTable
```

Comment: nice atitude but it didn't help either.